# Left to themselves -- is a 'when' needed?

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives

I read, in Arthur Bloch's hilarious "[Murphy's Law](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/009944545X)", the following corollary to Murphy's Law:

> Left to themselves, things tend to go from bad to worse.

Is that grammatical? Does the clause before the comma serve the purpose of an adjective (of *things*)? If it indeed acts like an adjective, does it need to be hyphenated?

Comment: It is perfectly normal to elide the word "when" as in "(When) left to themselves". And no, hyphens are not needed. It is an adjectival clause but not a pre-positioned adjective, as in "Red-hot things are dangerous".

Answer (score 1):

Either form is acceptable, but since "left to themselves" is a subordinate clause, you don't need to use "when."

Consider this restructuring that makes the clause a parenthetical modifier:

> Things, left to themselves, tend to go from bad to worse.

Also consider this example sentence [used in *The Elements of Style*](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk.html) by Strunk & White:

> Walking slowly down the road, he saw a woman accompanied by two children.

It has a similar structure to your proposed sentence.  The author could have chosen to write "**While** walking slowly..." or "**When** walking," but a modifier of that sort is not necessary.